# How to copy only one file from a GitHub repository to local machine?

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on GitHub which has the code of a project that I am working on.

While working, I deleted a file from my local machine. So, now I want to copy the file from my GitHub repository to my local machine.

Initially I thought I should `clone` the repository and then copy the required file locally in my machine.

But is there a way to get only one file without having to clone the entire repository? Preferably from the command line ? (just like how we `clone` from CLI using  `git clone ...`)

Comment: Isn't the file still part of the commits of the repository? You can revert the deletion.

Comment: But why don't you want to have a clone of the repo? Don't you normally work from within a clone?

Comment: Do you have local repository at all?

Comment: You can go to github, browse the commit history, find the commit you want, browse the tree of that commit, find the file you want and finally download it.  You can replicate this in the CLI by using https://developer.github.com/v3/git/ .

Comment: @PSkocik Thanks for the link. But I need to know basics of git and github to understand that document. And i am unable to understand it.. is there is any other link which is not so complicated .. for a beginner ??

Comment: @nkcode Yes i i have a directory in my computer which has the code for my project. I thought it was understood ..

Comment: I'm afraid not. You really may be wanting a different thing than you think you want.

Comment: Try going to that local repo, and running `git checkout --THE_PATH_TO_THE_FILE_YOU_LOST`. Did you get the file back?

Comment: @PSkocik let me simplify my question. `If I want to download only ONE file from a github repository, how to do it from command line ?` Yes I can copy paste the code to gedit and save, but I want to do it from CLI ...

Comment: @PSkocik Worked !! Thanks. `git checkout --PATH_TO_FILE` worked !! Now I have it back in my local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way git repos work is you have the working tree and in it a `.git` directory  that contains a database with your project's history.
When you delete from the working tree, you can do `git checkout -- FILE` and git will go to that database and retrieve the latest version of the file (given the branch you're at).
You can delete anything in your working tree and as long as it once was committed to the database in .git (and kept there), it is immediately recoverable.

I recommend you read up or take a course on some basics of git.
Take a look at https://www.codeschool.com/paths/git and 
http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2 .